# Using a previously defined command in a loop

Tags: loops

I have the following defined:

```
\newcommand{\pl}{\ensuremath{p^L}\xspace}
\newcommand{\pr}{\ensuremath{p^R}\xspace}
\newcommand{\xx}{\ensuremath{_{XX}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\xc}{\ensuremath{_{XC}}\xspace}
```

And I would now like to define

```
\newcommand{\plxx}{\ensuremath{\pl\xx}\xspace}
\newcommand{\plxc}{\ensuremath{\pl\xc}\xspace}
...
```

and so on. (I actually more than four...)

I tried to adapt [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78981/defining-commands-using-two-loops/)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\pl}{\ensuremath{p^L}}
\newcommand{\xx}{_{XX}}
\newcommand{\xc}{_{XC}}

\foreach \p in {xx,xc}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname pl\p\endcsname{%
     \noexpand\ensuremath{\pl\p}%
    }%
  }%

\begin{document}
$\plxc$ 
\end{document}
```

But it gives me the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.15 $\plxc
           $
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.16 \end{document}
```

Really sorry to bother you with this, since I already asked a similar question but I'm not able to adapt the solution to the other one...

Comment: You already have `\ensuremath`  in the foreach loop so remove the one in the definition of `\pl` or take it out in the loop. Also please read this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro

Comment: Thank you but I also need to use \pl as a standalone. What I have done is created a new \plbare and define the standalone \pl using that.

Comment: I still don't understand why doing all this stuff with `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` that only complicates things. What's so difficult in writing `$\pl$` instead of `\pl`? If it's math it *should* be written in math.

Comment: You're right, bad habit on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply say

```
\newcommand{\pl}{p^L}
\newcommand{\pr}{p^R}
\newcommand{\xx}{_{XX}}
\newcommand{\xc}{_{XC}}
```

so that

```
$\pl\xx$
```

would give the result you need. Clearer and simpler.

I really can't figure out why you would need `\xx` in text mode (so with `\ensuremath`).

There are *many* problems with abusing `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`; one you have found yourself: `$\pl\xx$`, which is the most natural syntax, doesn't work and you're forced to increase the number of commands to remember.

When you say "I need `\pl` also in text" you're wrong: you need to use a math formula in text, which is quite common and obtained by

```
\(\pl\)
```

(old timers like me are used to `$\pl$`) that will also appear marked up if you have a good editor.

---

If you *really* insist in using a wrong way of doing things, here's how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\pl}{\ensuremath{p^L}\xspace}
\newcommand{\pr}{\ensuremath{p^R}\xspace}
\newcommand{\xx}{\ensuremath{_{XX}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\xc}{\ensuremath{_{XC}}\xspace}

\begingroup
\def\ensuremath#1{#1}
\def\xspace{}

\foreach \p in {xx,xc}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname pl\p\endcsname{%
     \noexpand\ensuremath{\pl\csname\p\endcsname}\noexpand\xspace
    }%
  }
\endgroup

\begin{document}
Here \plxc is used in text

\texttt{\meaning\plxc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should suppress the expansion of the `\pl` in the loop too

Edit after the comment: And if you want to insert the command `\xx` (and not the string `xx`) you must use `\csname\p\endsname` or `\noexpand\csname\p\noexpand\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\pl}{\ensuremath{p^L}}
\newcommand{\xx}{_{XX}}
\newcommand{\xc}{_{XC}}

\foreach \p in {xx,xc}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname pl\p\endcsname{%
     \noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\pl\noexpand\csname\p\noexpand\endcsname}%
    }%
  }%


\begin{document}
$\plxc$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like \plxc to give me in the final: $p^L_{XC}$ whereas in your code it gives me $p^L xc$.

Comment: @Peutch: I have edited the answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\endcsname` isn't expandable by `\edef`.