# \foreach with \newcommand how to use them together?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pgffor

What I want to do is to shorten this `\newcommand` with a `\foreach` since this is just a very little part of what I will use.

```
\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}} % the set of complex numbers
\newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb N}} % the set of natural numbers
\newcommand{\QQ}{{\mathbb Q}} % the set of rational numbers
\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}} % the set of integer numbers
\newcommand{\DD}{{\mathbb D}} % the unit disk
\newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb R}} % the set of real numbers
\newcommand{\TT}{{\mathbb T}} % the unit circle (the one dimensional torus)
```

I tried this but it gives an error saying that command `\x` is already defined. Any suggestions?

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in {C,N,Q,Z,D,R,T}
{
\newcommand{\x\x}{{\matbb{\x}}}

};
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I believe that your question is just a special instance of the following one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators/361#361

Comment: tohecz needs to get off his high horse

Answer (score 14):

You need to expand and let LaTeX know that you mean a control sequence

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in {C,N,Q,Z,D,R,T}{\expandafter\xdef\csname\x\x\endcsname{\noexpand\mathbb{\x}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {C,N,Q,Z,D,R,T}{$\csname\x\x\endcsname$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly explain how this works (or reference relevant documentation)?

Comment: @Jollywatt (late note, also for future readers) \expandafter \xdef \csname \noexpand are all TeX primitive, refer to TeXbook/TeX by topic for documentation.

Answer (score 13):

You're better served with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeabbrev}{mmm}
 {
  \yoruk_makeabbrev:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yoruk_makeabbrev:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { #2 } { #1 { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeabbrev{\mathbb}{#1#1}{C,N,Q,Z,D,R,T}

\makeabbrev{\mathcal}{c#1}{A,B,C}

\begin{document}

$\CC\DD\TT\cA\cB\cC$

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\makeabbrev` is the math alphabet to use, the second argument is a template where `#1` stands for the current item when examining the letters in the list given as the third argument.

[image]

So with the first call we define `\CC` to stand for `\mathbb{C}` and so on, with the second call we define `\cA`, `\cB` and `\cC` to stand for `\mathcal{A}` and so on.

---

Why doesn't your attempt work? For three reasons.

1. Each cycle in `\foreach` is performed in a group, so a `\newcommand` in it will be immediately forgotten
2. Even if `\x\x` were substituted with, say, `CC` in the first cycle before `\newcommand` starts its work, `\newcommand{CC}` would be illegal anyway.
3. Even if you solved the first two problems, you'd still define `\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{\x}}` because `\newcommand` never expands its second argument.