# New command in a generic way

Tags: macros

I set this new command:

```
\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
```

I want to set the same command but now in a generic way. Something like that:

```
\newcommand{\##}{{\rm #}}
```

How to do that?

Edit: The new command that I set (`\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}`) only works
for the letter `d` right?

I want to write the same new command but now working with any letter.

Comment: Do you want `\newcommand{\myrm}[1]{{\rmfamily #1}}`? If not, please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. I think now is more clear.

Comment: Sorry but the edit still doesn't make things very clear. Are you looking for a way to define multiple *commands* (e.g. `\dd`, `\ee`, `\ff` etc.? Or just a way to a have a single command which will apply to anything you give it (which is @PhelypeOleinik 's solution.)  (Also, possibly unrelated to your actual problem, but you shouldn't use two-letter font macros in LaTeX.  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361).)

Comment: A way to a have a single command which will apply to anything I give it.

Comment: Then take a look at [\newcommand argument confusion](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358) (effectively a duplicate I think.)

Comment: For this particular use-case you do not need to define a macro becayse one already exists: you can write `\textrm{d}`, or `\textrm(Fred}`, or `\textrm{Julie}` or ...

Answer (score 7):

When you use `\newcommand`, you can give the number of "arguments" to that command. These arguments are "things" that you give to that command.

For example, a command *without* arguments is the one you showed:

```
\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
```

a command with *one* argument can be defined as:

```
%                ↓ number of arguments
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{{\rmfamily #1}}
%                              ↑↑ The first argument
```

so when you use it, the `#1` is replaced by the first argument. So when you type this:

```
\dd{hello}
```

is the `\dd` is replaced by:

```
{\rmfamily hello}
```

The same goes for a command with more arguments. For example:

```
%                ↓ number of arguments
\newcommand{\dd}[2]{{#1 #2}}
%                       ↑↑ The second argument
%                    ↑↑ The first argument
```

so you could use, for example:

```
\dd{\rmfamily}{hello}
```

which would be replaced by

```
{\rmfamily hello}
```

#### Optional arguments

You can define an optional argument by specifying the default value for it:

```
%                ↓ number of arguments
%                   ↓-------↓ Default value for the first argument
\newcommand{\dd}[2][\rmfamily]{{#1 #2}}
%                                  ↑↑ The second argument
%                               ↑↑ The first argument
```

so when you type

```
\dd{hello}
```

or

```
\dd[\rmfamily]{hello}
```

the substitution is the same:

```
{\rmfamily hello}
```

but if you type

```
\dd[\bfseries]{hello}
```

you would get **hello**!

P.S.: Don't use `\rm`, it's deprecated. Use `\rmfamily` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can't set a macro with unknown name so that TeX interprets the macros name and if there are two identical letters uses `{\rmfamily <letter>}`, if that's what you meant. (Actually this might be possible, since you can do almost anything with TeX, but doesn't seem like a good idea to me.)

What you however can do, is writing a wrapper around your `\newcommand` that simplifies the definition of such macros:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand*\rmify[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#1\endcsname{{\rmfamily #1}}%
  }
\rmify{d}
\rmify{r}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
d\dd r\rr
\end{document}
```

If the usage is for math mode, change the definition of `\rmify` in above's example to:

```
\newcommand*\rmify[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#1\endcsname{\mathrm{#1}}
  }
```

Comment: I didn't exactly know what OP was asking for. What you did would be my second guess :)

Comment: I’m inclined to think that the definition is for math mode, maybe you can add this case.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking for setting up TeX so that

> whenever the control sequence `\xx` is found (with `x` any letter), then `\mathrm{x}` is produced.

However this is not possible with a simple instruction similar to the one you'd like to type. Every control sequence must have its own definition.

However, with some tricks it's possible to do “batch definitions” with a common pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\count@=`\a\loop
\begingroup\lccode`X=\count255
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \@ifundefined{XX}
    {\expandafter\newcommand\csname XX\endcsname{\mathrm{X}}}
    {\typeout{not redefining \@backslashchar XX}}%
}
\ifnum\count@<`\z \advance\count@ by 1 \repeat
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\aa} % not changed

\texttt{\meaning\bb}

\texttt{\meaning\zz}

\end{document}
```

This will print

[image]

and the console will show

```
not redefining \aa
not redefining \gg
not redefining \ll
not redefining \ss
not redefining \tt
```

Note: I assume that you want to use `\dd` and similar commands in math mode, but the syntax `{\rm d}` has been deprecated for more than twenty years; the correct syntax is `\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: Nice, as usual! However, even for a medium-experienced LaTeX hacker like me the underlying TeX trickery is hard to read. I assume that, especially for beginner-level questions, an answer based on LaTeX3 or at least `etoolbox` might be more accessible.

Comment: @Daniel You can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207992/4427 for a much better way.

Comment: I should have done this (thought of it, but was too lazy...)