# Is it possible to auto infer macros which have a common prefix?

Tags: macros

Let say that I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\def\cal#1{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\calA}{\cal A}

\begin{document}

Let \calA be a linearly ordered set.

\end{document}
```

Now, imagine that I need to use a lot mathcal for single letters, how can I make latex auto infer/auto generate the definition for the `\calX` where X is a capital letter. Of course, I could generate 26 newcommands but I would prefer not to do that.

I mean that I would like that I had not to put a space between `\cal` and `X`. Is there any trick available to do that?

Comment: You gain nothing by using `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` in place of the simpler and more semantic `$\calA$`. There are a few answers on the site about defining families of commands like those you want. See, for instance, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207992/4427

Comment: Yes, I do not save much by using `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`. It just save two characters but takes more times to process for latex. I am more interested in how to generate such families of commands. I already tried searching but I don't think I am using the right keywords.

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, I could use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173236/51088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control sequence is either defined or undefined. There's no way to say

> Hey, TeX, if you find a control sequence starting with `\cal` followed by an uppercase letter, say `X`, and which is currently undefined, define it so that it does `\mathcal{X}`.

Well, there might be some *very fragile* ways to do it. The trade between using complex and fragile code or defining the macros you need is in favor of the latter.

It's much simpler to use code suggested for [Automatically generate new commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173236/51088) or the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207992/4427 for batch defining the macros you need.

About `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`, I recommend sticking instead to `$\calA$`, that's not much harder to type and carries more semantics.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xspace}
\newcommand\makecalx[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname cal#1\endcsname{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}\xspace}%
}
\readlist\callets{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\foreachitem\z\in\callets[]{\expandafter\makecalx\expandafter{\z}}
\begin{document}
Here is \calG and \calZ.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that you generate all the commands at once. Since the set of letters is small that is a reasonable choice. I am also wondering whether it would be possible to generate lazily commands on demand. `\calG` would trigger `\calG` if it exists and if it does not exists it would then trigger its creation through something like your macro `\makecalx`.

Comment: @永劫回帰 I think the answer is no, because `\calG` is not `\cal` with an argument of `G`, but rather its own macro `\calG`.  It is either defined or it isn't.  If it isn't, TeX produces an error.  Thus, for this type of syntax, all cases have to be dealt with in advance of their use.  If you changed the syntax to `\cal{G}`, perhaps something could be done.

Comment: I see, thank you, that makes sense.