# TeXstudio not recognizing custom commands

Tags: texstudio

I have been trying to implement the code given in the answer by percusse in [\foreach with \newcommand how to use them together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207985/foreach-with-newcommand-how-to-use-them-together). The code seems to work, however TeXstudio does not recognize the new commands (i.e. in highlights them orange).

Here is the code in my situation:

```
\foreach \x in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname cal\x\endcsname{\noexpand\mathcal{\x}}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname scr\x\endcsname{\noexpand\mathscr{\x}}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname frak\x\endcsname{\noexpand\mathfrak{\x}}
}
```

which allows me to write things like `$\calA$` to display mathcal A. However, the `\calA` appears as an "unrecognized command" (i.e. it is highlighted orange) in TeXstudio.

I have all of the usual packages like amsmath, amsfont, amssymb, etc. loaded.

**Question:** how can I get these custom commands to be recognized by TeXstudio?

---

For clarity, here is all of the packages that I have loaded:

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                           DOCUMENT CLASS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                             BIBLATEX
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\AtBeginBibliography{\small}
\usepackage{microtype}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                             HYPERREFS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, 
    urlcolor     = cyan, 
    linkcolor    = blue, 
    citecolor   = blue 
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labeltext}[3][]{%
    \@bsphack%
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname% in case hyperref is used
    \def\tst{#1}%
    \def\labelmarkup{}% How to markup the label itself
    %\def\refmarkup{\labelmarkup}% How to markup the reference
    \def\refmarkup{}%
    \ifx\tst\empty\def\@currentlabel{\refmarkup{#2}}{\label{#3}}%
    \else\def\@currentlabel{\refmarkup{#1}}{\label{#3}}\fi%
    \@esphack%
    \labelmarkup{#2}% visible printed text.
}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                        FONTS AND MATH PACKAGES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                       TIKZ AND DIAGRAMS PACKAGES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{tikzit}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                     TABLES, FIGURES, LISTS PACKAGES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[linewidth=0pt]{mdframed}
\usepackage{subfig}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                    HEADERS, FOOTNOTES, CHAPTERS, ETC. PACKAGES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom, perpage]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%_____Bold sections
\patchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
\makeatother

%_____Minimal spacing chapter titles
%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries\doublespacing}{\thechapter}{20pt}{}{}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{40pt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                           GENERAL FORMATTING
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25em}

%_____Numbering equations, figures, and theorems all the same by section
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@figure
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could write a custom .cwl file and list all the new commands there. However is this really worth the effort? If textudio recognises or not recognises a command does not have any influence on the result.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think to do that I would need to list each individual command, right? Like \calA, \calB, \calC, etc. My issue is definitely not significant, but I am still curious if there is a way to solve this problem.

Comment: See the texstudio [manual](https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format) and many examples [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/tree/master/completion)

Comment: You could just use `\cal A`, `\cal B` and define `\newcommand*\scr[1]{\mathscr{#1}}` and `\newcommand*\Frak[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}` and use `\scr A` as well as `\Frak B` without having to define 52×3 commands.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it's a very minor time-saver, but I have it all as one command (e.g. ``\calA`` vs. ``\cal A``) with no spaces so that way when I use it in a subscript or something, I don't need to use curly braces.

Comment: I usually turn off this function in TeXstudio: Options / Configure TeXstudio / Editor / Syntax (no checked)